# Keyboard covering textview on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I am newbie for iPhone application. Below is what I have...

[image]

When I enter Item name, I get proper screen with Done option. When I click Done, keyboard get hided.

[image]

Same happen for Time also.

Now when I click on description and type something, I get screen as below.

[image]

**Now my problem is, I can't see `UITextView` and because of that I can't see what I am typing.**

**How can I show the `UITextView` so that I can see what I am typing.**

---

### Update 1

[image]

Comment: That is a design problem, you shouldn't put the textview there. But maybe you can use a UIScrollerView, it might scroll the view, so you can see the text while you are writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First take these whole controls in `UIScrollView` and set as it is,

after just in `UITextView` delegate method `textViewDidBeginEditing` set the frame of view like bellow...

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(yourScrollView.frame.origin.x, -160, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, yourScrollView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

and also set same like before after return like bellow...

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(yourScrollView.frame.origin.x, 0, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, yourScrollView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

you can also set the frame of `UIView` instead of `UIScrollView`..

Also first give the Delegate to `UITextView` and add this delegate in `.h` file

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: i think this will be good option against uiscrollview... i will check tomorrow and get. back to you incase of any queries...

Comment: sure post comment if you get any query.. :)

Comment: how can I set the scroll bar to visible of the scrollview?

Comment: what I want is when I focus on description textarea, I want to see Scroller i.e. white line for scrolling up and down...

Comment: oh you mean you want to see the scroller on uitextview?? then its displayed automatically when you data in uitextview is more then the frame of uitextview .. but here for that uitextview's ShowsVerticalScrollers property must checked..

Comment: no, not in textview. When I am using UIScrollView, I was under impression that I will see scrollbar at the right side, however I don't see. Now what I want is, when I click on UITextView, I can see UIScrollView scroll bar... I hope you get now...

Comment: just in viewDidLoad method try to set some contentOffset of scrollview then check it.. i.e     [scrView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];

Comment: I will update the question... I added `[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 340)];`, still that is not solving problem. Once I update question, I will let you know

Comment: @FahimParkar hey dude post new quetion instead of update the quetion its good for more info from another user also so...

Comment: @FahimParkar hey just see dude what i want to say that for that you can just descrese the height of scrollview and set contentoffset here dude...

Comment: and also set contentOffSet more than the height of scrollview and you will see the scroller when you just scroll the scrolllview after automatically its unvisible..

Comment: Why I  want scrollview is if I don't want to write in textview how can  I go back to other textfield?

Comment: like every application user click the return key of keyboard and you got normal uiscrollview which you see at starting or before the textview become editing so.. now got it dude??

Comment: can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235433/how-to-find-the-row-detail-of-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 2):

set following code in viewDidLoad for key board hide/show notification

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

and set this method and change the frame of view in this code

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the content in a `UIScrollView` and use the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` to scroll to the correct `TextField` when it is active.

Also you have to resize the scrollview according to if the keyboard is shown or not, so you need to set up `TextField delegates`

Answer (score 1):

Used `UIScrollView` in design behind all controls & set the `contentsize` of it on `beginEditing` of `TextView` or `TextFieldShouldReturn` of second(time) textfield.