# How to find/ delete the CUSTOM row detail of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

This question is bit related to my earlier question

I am newbie for iPhone application and trying to learn `UITableView` with `JSON`. I followed [`this video`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k) for learning.

I created same example using Stoaryboard and also added new screen where I can add data. Now I was trying to delete the data. So what I did is thought is instead of below method, I will add button on each row and on clicking of that I will delete the data.

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

But I am not getting how I will get the row details and how to delete.

Any help/ suggestion would be grateful.

Below is how my screen looks like.

[image]

### Note:

**The `UITableViewCell` is of CUSTOM type.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the data model according to edit actions delete using bellow code.

This bellow code is just an example for hot to delete or remove the object from array and also from table .. for more info check the tutorial which i post the link bellow..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

         [arryData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tblSimpleTable reloadData];

     } 
}
```

or also using this bellow logic with custom button of cell...

```
- (IBAction)deleteCustomCellWithUIButton:(id)sender
{
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]];
  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  [yourTableView removeObjectAtIndex:row];
  [yourTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

For more info  refer these tutorial...

1. [iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-UITableView-row](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/)
2. [multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html)

Comment: thanks Paras.. I shall check and get back to you incase of any queries.

Comment: I am pulling data from live database. So I believe this will not work. What I believe is, when I click on row 0, I should get id of that row so that I can use that Id to delete the data. Also for this, I would need to set tag while adding the delete button. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @FahimParkar hey here no need for create some special code for that , here roland say is also right here with this example you can get idea that how can you add or delete raw at runtime but also you can delete data from live also .. just put some logic here and you can got it dude..

Comment: @FahimParkar here you need to just remove data from web same as you delete data from array and also you can implement the logic with tag if you use custom button for delete raw.. also lookup in http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-delete-data-from-tableview-in-iphone/ this link hope this helpful to you dude.. :)

Comment: @FahimParkar i update my answer for how to delete raw and data from custom button tap event dude... :)

Comment: how can I take integer value from `[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]`?

Comment: [[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]; try this if not get then post comment

Comment: hey can you take a look at my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301523/language-switcher-in-ios6)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button on each row and set the `button.tag` to the `indexPath.row` in the `cellForRowAtIndex:` method. Then in your button method you can delete the entry from the `Array` that is used to populate the `UITableView` and then `reloadData`

Comment: can you provide me link for this example?

Comment: There is no link for this, you have to code it yourself, let me know if you need more information and what is unclear

Comment: Ok, I got what you meant to say and I am implementing the same. Thanks for showing the Path :)

Comment: You are welcome :) If you like the answer, please upvote and accept if its correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to get cell or indexPath of cell:

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows

If you want to handel IBAction of UIButton than use indexPathForRowAtPoint like this :

```
-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{

CGPoint location            = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath      = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell *swipeCell  = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"Selected row: %d", indexPath.row);
//......

}
```

OR indexPathForCell

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   // Get the UITableViewCell which is the superview of the UITableViewCellContentView which is the superview of the UIButton
   (UITableViewCell*)cell = [[button superview] superview];
   int row = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell].row;
}
```

I have taken code from :
[Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

[Custom UITableViewCell button action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399119/custom-uitableviewcell-button-action)