# Is there RTL support in iPhone Application (Stoaryboard)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, layout, ios6, right-to-left

I am newbie for iPhone application. I am fine with English and Arabic text (selecting language at the start of application) however just curious how to format the screen from LTR to RTL.

**Is there support in iPhone storyboard for RTL in layout?**

---

### Answer

I have asked somewhat same question and there I found answer.

[How to set Arabic text to right and English text to left on same label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335536/how-to-set-arabic-text-to-right-and-english-text-to-left-on-same-label)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am definetly NOT an expert, but I do use hebrew in my iOS apps.
iOS 6 SDK has something called "Auto-Layout", and the guide specifies that it enables you not to worry about RTL languages.

> Cocoa Auto Layout allows individual views to declare their own preferred size, which means you don’t have to specify new layout if the label’s text changes—for example, because of localization, as illustrated in the right window. You don’t even have to specify new layout for languages like Hebrew and Arabic in which the left to right ordering of elements themselves should generally be reversed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, if you can view a language in a browser on the iphone you can try using a technology like phonegap.

Comment: Please don't vote this down - this is an alternate programming solution. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/arabic_support_help

Comment: The title after all ask whether or not it exists....

Comment: those are not iPhone app... those are called website and using css they made look like iPhone app...

Comment: Incorrect sir! Phonegap is a compiled web container served directly on the iphone, and what is more it allows for native hooks to be called through javascript: please review the following http://www.practicaldeveloper.net/2011/09/creating-plugin-with-phonegap-10.html  and don't penalize me for what you haven't discovered yet please. Note the detailed objective-C involved.